# How to find & replace a pattern with string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, shell

My file is:

```
    [root@test etc]# cat nrpe.cfg

    command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 30 -c 35
    command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
    command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sda1
    command[check_hda]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sdb
    command[check_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 200 -c 250
```

I Want to replace */dev/sdb* with */dev/xvda1* in ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's write the text to a file:

```
str =<<BITTER_END
command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 30 -c 35
command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sda1
command[check_hda]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sdb
command[check_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 200 -c 250
BITTER_END

Fname_in  = "in"
Fname_out = "out"

File.write(Fname_in, str)
  #=> 390
```

Now read that file into a string, modify the string and write it to the output file:

```
File.write(Fname_out, File.read(Fname_in).gsub("/dev/sdb", "/dev/xvda1"))
  #=> 392
```

Let's confirm it worked:

```
puts File.read(Fname_out)
command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 30 -c 35
command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sda1
command[check_hda]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/xvda1
command[check_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 200 -c 250
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) or [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-sub) depending on number of occurrences in a line:

```
line = "command[check_hda]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sdb"
line.gsub("/dev/sdb", "/dev/xvda1")
#=> "command[check_hda]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/xvda1"
```

Since its in a file, you can iterate over as:

```
File.open("/your/file", "r") { |file| file.each_line { |line|
puts line.gsub("/dev/sdb", "/dev/xvda1")
}}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `gsub` & `sub`?

Comment: `gsub` replaces all occurrences of pattern, `sub` will replace only the first occurrence. I have provided link in my answer, please go through docs.